# Displaying XML Contents in a table + easy search with php

Tags: php, html, mysql, xml

first i want sorry for my bad English.

Im not pro in php/html/xml.

I have xml file "bans.xml" with users (example with 1 user):

```
`
<ban>
<datetime>30/09/2013 08:20:33 GMT Standard Time</datetime>
<nick>Player 1</nick>
<method>Key</method>
<period>Perm</period>
<address>IP ADRESS</address>
<profileid>PROFILE ID</profileid>
<cdkeyhash>871358843</cdkeyhash>
<by>21 from IP name='Im Admin 1'</by>
<reason>Reason 1</reason>
<whenBanned>0001-01-01T00:00:00</whenBanned>
</ban>
`
```

And I want display this on html or php. If someone like it can by with mysql base.

I need this in easy table with possible to search per Nick.

With displaying:

nick / by (if possible only name='nick') / datetime (if possible without this "GMT Standart Time") / reason

If its possible can automatic sort by "Date" (new -> old) in default list ?

Example:

```
`
Search:
[write here your nickname] [[Button Search]] 
_______________________________________
# | NICKNAME | Admin | Date | Reason |
________________________________________
1.| Player x | Im Admin 1 | 30/09/2013 08:21:56 |  Reason 1
2.| Player y | Im Admin 2 | 30/09/2013 08:20:30 |  Test

`
```

If someone write nickname and he is on list it show only his data.
If he isnt on list it show somthing like "You are not banned".

Thanks a lot someone who help :)
Best Regrads.

Comment: What did you already tried to get the result?

Comment: It is very possible to do this with PHP, but as Joran said, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes,of course. I give you everything i do but i must wait because i cant answer. I get error: "Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**only guide to have you're own idea ;-)** dont use on production server - only guide

1. Read xml
2. Parse xml
3. Output xml into html table
4. Apply jquery datatables

HINT* 
Make you're own function to extract datetime, clean the code, this is dirty! Think about if exist XML file and working with file over PHP

**DEMO**

http://www.cdn.houba.info/xml/

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  </body>

  <table id="example">

    <thead>
      <tr>        
        <th>Nick</th>
        <th>Admin</th>
        <th>Date / Time</th>
        <th>Reason</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

  <?php

  // XXXXXXX - local source, 
  // ex.. 'ban.xml' 

  $url = ('XXXXXXX');
  $xml = simplexml_load_file( urlencode($url), null, true);


  ?>

  <?php foreach ( $xml->ban as $b ) :?>
      <tr>        
        <td><?php echo $b->nick; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $b->by; ?></td>
        <!-- THIS IS DIRTY, JUST FOR EXAMPLE -->
        <td><?php echo mb_substr( $b->datetime, 0, 19 ); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $b->reason; ?></td>
      </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>

   </tbody>
  </table>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#example').dataTable( {
          "sScrollY": 200,
          "bJQueryUI": true,
          "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
      } );
  } );
</script> 


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank You a lot, its better than i dream. I try work with your code. I give you my code in some hours in answer because now i get error: "Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking."

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for fast reaply. Im not this type guy who dont do anything, write everywhere post "Help" and wait to someone do for him all work.

I forget with question get my code what i do (not my work - google everything to find answer and red some tutroials).

```
'
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("ban.xml");
?>
<?php 
/* pobieramy datę ostatniej modyfikacji pliku ban.xml */ 
$ostatnio_mod = filemtime("ban.xml"); 
/* Wyświetlamy wynik */ 
print("Generated: "); 
print(date("j-m-y h:i:s", $ostatnio_mod));
?>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Nickname</th>
<th>Admin</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Reason</th>
</tr>

<?php foreach ($xml->ban as $ban) :?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $ban->nick; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $ban->by; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $ban->datetime; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $ban->reason; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
</table>
<br>
<br>
<?php
echo "TOP Admins";
echo "<br>";
$getText = file_get_contents("ban.xml", true);
$Test = substr_count($getText ,"Test");

$Im_Admin = substr_count($getText ,"Im Admin");
$All_Admins = substr_count($getText ,"Im Admin","Test");
$getAdmins = $Test - $Im_Admin ;
echo "Test =". $getAdmins;

echo "<br>";
echo "Im_Admin =". $Im_Admin ;
echo "<br>";
echo "All Admins BANs:". $All_Admins ;
?> 
'
```

But if you see not everything i can do. I have trobule with "search" - its the worst :/ I don't know how: 1) cut out in Admin - 21 from 62.247.128.108 name='Test' and only show "Test" 2) in Date - cut out "GMT Standard Time"

But i see Honza.M do just what i try do. I try work with your code because in html is the best option for me but php its still possible.

If someone can (or you Honza) upgrade your code it will be cool. I try one more thing to do a mobile version of your code. Something like:

```
'
[Search]
Nickname 1
Nickname 2
Nickname 3
'
```

When someone write his nickname in [Search] and show him, he can press his nickname and get full page with info:

```
'
You Are Banned
Your Nickname: Nickname 1
Banned by Admin: Test
Date of ban: 1/01/2013 8:08:00

Reason: Cheating
'
```

Ok i see lots to do so i back to work :), if someone have any suggestions or can help please write :) It will be very helpfull.

Thanks a lot Honza.M and everybody.